# Should I shut down RP3 using command line or GUI?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, shutdown

I am a pretty new user of Raspberry Pi, and I booted it just once so far.

I used NOOBS to install Raspbian on a microSD card for my RP3. When I wanted to shut it down afterwards, I Googled it to learn the proper way to do so.

My expectation was the shut down button on the GUI drop down menu of Raspbian *[see photo below]* to be the preferred way. However, it seemed that there wasn't a unanimous decision about the *right way* to shut it down. Most answers I have found didn't even mention the GUI at all.

[image]

So what should I do? Is using the mentioned button OK? Or should I use a command in terminal? Is there really a difference at all?

Comment: The shutdown button will work just fine, of course there are terminal commands that will have the same effect. As long as you are not yanking out the power cable whilst the Pi is running, you are not going to run into any problems.

Comment: @DarthVader Hey there! Thanks for your reply. Is it normal that Raspbian boots into GUI directly? On most of answers I see on this side, a command-line-based OS is mentioned.

Comment: It defaults to gui however that can be changed by running raspi-config and changing appropriate setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutting down the Pi properly can be done using either the GUI or the command-line. All the GUI does is invoke the proper command-line command.

Different OS's and different users will have different setups as to whether the Pi boots to the GUI or to the command-line. Raspbian defaults to the GUI since it endeavors to be user-friendly for new users not familiar with Linux. As mentioned in one of the comments, this can be changed back and forth using the `raspi-config` utility.

Comment: Is the GUI button option very new? Because most of old topics I found, almost all to be honest, mentions nothing about it.

Comment: @SarpSTA Some GUIs have it, some don't. Since the older Pi's were kinda weak when you load a GUI, most people only ever use the command-line.

Comment: There are different types of GUIs in Raspbian?

Comment: You can change the GUI in Raspbian, and there are different OS's that have their own GUI. A popular alternative is XFCE --> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=7571